# MSVC 2015 cannot compile constexpr atan

Tags: c++, visual-studio, c++11

I have used `Mingw-w64` compiler in my project. Now I am compiling the project with `MSVC2015`. The following line gives an error:

```
constexpr double pi = 4*std::atan(1);
```

error:

```
error: C2131: expression did not evaluate to a constant
```

However it compiled in mingw without any problems.

Comment: Probably std::atan() is constexpr in Mingw-w64 compiler and is not in MSVC2015 implementation. Compare this function declarations in  <cmath> header files shipped with Mingw-64 and same file shipped with Visual Studio

Comment: This looks like a gcc bug.  Clang and MSVS both reject the code rightly IMHO.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MSVC is right in this case, from [[constexpr.functions]p1](http://eel.is/c++draft/constexpr.functions#1)

> This document explicitly requires that certain standard library functions are constexpr. **An implementation shall not declare any standard library function signature as constexpr except for those where it is explicitly required.**

As you can see from the last sentence that I highlighted, an implementation is not allowed to declare a function `constexpr` if the standard doesn't say so.

Now does the standard say that `atan` is `constexpr`? No, as can be seen from the signature in [[c.math]](http://eel.is/c++draft/c.math):

> ```
> float atan(float x);  // see [library.c]
> double atan(double x);
> ```

Comment: @Yola In C `atan` cannot be used in a constant expression, while mingw allows it.

Comment: Do you mean C doesn't allow expressions like `const double d[(int)(atan(2))]; d[0] = 1.;`?

Comment: @Yola I think C has VLAs, so that would be allowed (except the assignment). But there are probably some other contexts where a constant expression is required, but I can't think of any. Are there none?

Comment: @Yola Fixed the answer with a better reference, thanks for bringing this up :)